# codeigniter active record suggestion

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

In mysql I can query as following:

```
select studentname,'student' as profession from students
```

It returns something like:

```
studentname | profession  
------------+-----------
name1       | student  
name2       | student  
...
```

But how can I do so in codeigniter using active records? I am a newbie to CI, so your help is appreciated.

Note: Just to clear my question, there is no column named `student` or `profession` in the students table. `student` is a fixed text that I want to have with my resultset.

If I query something like:

```
$this->db->select("studentname, student as profession")->from('students')
```

then it gives error as it try to find student column while it's just a static value.

Comment: i think you should read thoroughly before asking the question here.

Comment: @MukeshSoni I didnt find such example in CI user guide

Comment: i am asking you to learn about active records. Learn about how it's different from normal database access.

Comment: @MukeshSoni I have updated my question. Hope it will help to understand where I am getting error.

Comment: select has a second option. Set it to false and try - 
$this->db->select('studentname, "student" as profession', false)->from('students')

Comment: Thanks Mukesh. Was not clear about the second option setting false. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select has a second option. Set it to false and try -

```
$this->db->select('studentname, "student" as profession', false)->from('students')
```